# Creating a loop of random numbers in VBA

Tags: vba

For my Assignment I am asked to create a loop of random numbers in VBA and make the loop stop when it is another previously generated number on my excel sheet. However when I run my code it constantly repeats one number instead of creating new random numbers.

```
Sub Ticket()

Dim R As Integer
Dim i As Integer

i = 0

  Randomize
  R = Int((999 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
  


Do Until R = Cells(19, 6)

Range("B18").Offset(i, 0) = R

i = i + 1

    
Loop



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

the rnd should be in the loop.

and get in the practice of declaring the parent sheet of all range objects.

The `Until` should be at the bottom.

```
Sub Ticket()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Do
            Randomize
            
            Dim R As Long
            R = Int((999 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
            
            .Range("B18").Offset(i, 0) = R
            
            i = i + 1
        Loop Until R = .Cells(19, 6)
    End With
End Sub
```